# How to check cumulative size of an hdfs directory as part of oozie action?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

As part of oozie workflow, I am trying to find the total cumulative size of an hdfs directory (which contains sub-directories where files are present). I tried with fs:dirSize function as part of oozie action, but this function returns size as 0 even though there are files present within sub-directory.

As per oozie documentation, fs:dirSize(String path) does not work recursively, only computes the size of the files under the specified path. Please advise how to get the cumulative size which considers files within sub-directories.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5" name="sample_WF">
<start to="decisionCheck"/>
<decision name="decisionCheck">
<switch>
<case to="end">
${fs:dirSize('/tmp/testOozie') gt 0}
</case>
<default to="fail"/>
</switch>
</decision>
<kill name="fail">
<message>***Failed***</message>
</kill>
<end name="end" />
</workflow-app>
```

Comment: Can you use the "hdfs dfs -du" command from a shell action ?  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#du

Comment: I want this action to be performed as part of oozie workflow. Please advise

Comment: You can use the shell action as part of your workflow